# domain objects and repository

Tags: domain-driven-design

I learn the DDD only 2 days, and the following question with the code?

```
public class User
{
    public Int UserId{get;set;}
    public string Username{get;set;}
    public List<Role> Roles{get;set;}

    public User GetUserById(int userid)
    {

      // How to write the business logic?

      // How to instance userRepository?

      return userRepository.GetUserById(userid);

    }

    public List<Role> GetRoles(int userid)
    {
       // How to write ?
    }

}

public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUserById(int userid);
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
  public User GetUserById(int userid)
  {

    ///ado.net code list from database

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear question here, i can only observe what i can see:

Why do you have a method called `GetUserById` in your domain model class (User)? This should not be here - this should be in your repository (which it is). It's like your calling through to your Repository via your Domain Model - which is **wrong**. Your Repository is an abstraction of your domain model. Remove this method.

Your presentations should instantiate your Repositories, which perform operations on the domain model, and return back to the presentation.

Your domain model **should not depend on anything**.

If you have any other specific questions please edit your question and i'll attempt to answer.